# Drupal alias to the last node of one type

Tags: nodes, path-aliases

Imagine I have a node type of congress, i want to create a menu called congress.html how always go to the last node of this type.

How can i do it.

Comment: Welcome.  I'm afraid you are going to have to get a bit more specific about this, eg, creating a menu called congress.html doesn't really make much sense with respect to Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is neither an alias, nor a menu. You want a view of nodes, filtered by type and sorted by date, that displays 1 item.